# Setting JS variable to PHP variable error

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use a php login name in my javascript game...

I have this at the top of my php page that runs the javascript:

```
<?php
$username = (isset($_GET['username']) ? ($_GET['username']) : "dude");
?>
```

In my javascript I have this... which doesn't alert the name at all and throws a `Uncaught ReferenceError: daniel is not defined` error:

```
var name = <?php echo $username; ?>;
alert(name);
```

And then I have this... which displays the name correctly at the top of the HTML:

```
<?php  
  echo "Welcome back " . $username . "...";
?>
```

If the name is being displayed correctly server side when the page has loaded, why can't it be alerted out from the Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't delimiting the value as a JavaScript string. It may be a string on the server, but not on the client. Do the following:

Change this:

```
var name = <?php echo $username; ?>;
```

To this:

```
var name = "<?php echo $username; ?>";
```

Comment: No worries dude, happens to all of us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your php code within quotes.Try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = '<?php echo $username; ?>';
    alert(name);  
</script>
```